# Display the Operator properties of an Active Add Primitive operator

Tags: python, scripting

is it possible to display the Operator properties of an Active Add Primitive operator in a Custom Panel
as in the following figure:

[image]

For cylinder, I have enter radius and height, ...

Comment: "Number of Cube?"  what you expect the number beside it to do, make 50 randomly placed cubes? .. or divide the cube in 50 sections per side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display them, but i think you will get convoluted code.

```
def draw(self, context):

    # ... earlier stuff.

    operators = bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].operators    
    if operators and operators[-1].name == 'Add UV Sphere':
        this_op = operators[-1]
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(this_op.properties, 'segments')
```

But you'll notice you can drag the slider, it will update the visible value but not update the actual value of the active operator.

[image]

Then dynamically populating the UI with properties:

```
 >>> bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].operators[-1].properties.items()
 ...[('size', 2.0), ('view_align', 0), ('enter_editmode', 0), ('layers', <bpy id property array [20]>), ('location', <bpy id property array [3]>), ('segments', 9)]
```

so..

```
def draw(self, context):
    obj = context.active_object
    mode_string = context.mode
    edit_object = context.edit_object

    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column()
    col.label(text="Generate objects:")

    if mode_string == 'OBJECT':
        layout.menu("INFO_MT_add", text="Add")
    elif mode_string == 'EDIT_MESH':
        layout.menu("INFO_MT_mesh_add", text="Add")

    operators = bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].operators    
    if operators and operators[-1].name == 'Add UV Sphere':
        this_op = operators[-1]
        col = layout.column()
        for k, v in this_op.properties.items():
            col.prop(this_op.properties, k)
```

Would produce this, by inspecting the items in the properties of the current operator.

[image]

But, there are fundamental problems with this. You would have to limit somehow the kind of Operators to show in this list. Right now i've limited to `Add UV Sphere`, if you don't do that it will show all most recent Operator properties even if they aren't a *Primitive* operator..

So you might construct a set of Operator names to allow..

```
showable = {'Add UV Sphere', 'Add Cube', ....... }
if operators and operators[-1].name in showable:
   # ... display them as shown above
```

And still you won't be able to tweak these props. `:(`

Seen as the operator has a perfectly good Operator Properties panel accessible from <kbd>F6</kbd>, and the panel also appears in the `'TOOLS'` shelf, I'm inclined to discourage trying to do this. -- But it's an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: I do not know where I put additions
As well as for each body of his properties
For example, the cylinder diameter and its height

Comment: Then I suggest you start scripting something smaller and read the the [cookbook too](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets)

Comment: how to add there lines

Comment: Where add these lines 
At the beginning of the script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32868/discussion-between-zeffii-and-saded).

Comment: @zeffii do you want this as a community wiki?

Comment: @David yep. Or the whole answer deleted :)